# How can I use VichUploaderBundle symfony2 to upload a pdf file in a form with ajax request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I used  VichUploaderBundle  in my project symfony 2to upload file , when i use the entityname/new all works fine , but now i want to upload it with ajax to don't reload the page , but it not working , this is my code ajax :

```
 $ur='http://127.0.0.1/QualiMaker/web/app_dev.php/formateur/new';
                            $.ajax({
                                url: $ur,
                                type: "POST",
                                data: new FormData($('form')[0]),
                                processData: false,
                                contentType: false,
                                cache: false,....
```

Comment: Kdous I dont think this has anything to do with the bundle, but upload files with ajax itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: you mean that i can upload th file without the bundle just with ajax ?